# How to write a sql query to sum total for each day?

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate-functions

Please help me to write the following sql. I have a table like this, with an amount column and date column

```
amount     date
-----------------------
100    -    2010-02-05
200    -    2010-02-05
50     -    2010-02-06
10     -    2010-02-06
10        2010-02-07
```

what I want is to write a sql to get total for each day. Ultimately my query should return something like this

```
amount     date
-----------------
300  -     2010-02-05
60   -     2010-02-06
10   -     2010-02-07
```

Please note that now it has group by dates and amounts are summed for that date.

## RESOLVED -

This was my bad, even though I mention the date column as date here, my actual date column in postgres table was 'timestamp'. Once I changed it to get the date only, everything got working

my working sql is like this "select sum(amount), date(date)
from bills
group by date(date)
"

thanks everyone (and I will accept the 1st answer as the correct answer since I can accept only one answer)

thanks again

sameera

Comment: What have you tried?  We're not here to do it all for you.  Also, is the date column a varchar, or a DATE/TIME column?

Comment: How about something like `SELECT SUM(amount), date GROUP BY date`?

Comment: Hi OMG

I have tried this 

"select sum(amount), date 
from bills 
group by date"

but the dates are repeating

thanks 

sameera

Comment: You've got enough rep to know how to tag questions, and format...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pretty basic `group by` statement.

```
SELECT SUM(table.amount), table.date
FROM table
GROUP BY table.date
```

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp

Answer (score 2):

Look into `GROUPING` by date, here: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp

and look into `SUM()`, here: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_func_sum.asp

You will need to use both of them.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT SUM(Amount), Date FROM Table
GROUP BY Date
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT SUM(amount) as amount_sum, date FROM table GROUP BY date;
```